# Count number of instances of a specific value and join results with another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: Table 1 (User) contains names of users/leaders and Table 2 (Transactions) contains records of user transactions with a column named "reason"

There are several "reasons" which can be grouped into 2 categories.

```
User Table
--------------
User   Leader
--------------
user1  Leader1
user2  Leader1
user3  Leader2
user4  Leader2


Transaction Table
-----------------------------------
User   Leader   Reason
-----------------------------------
user1  Leader1  Category 1 Reason 1
user1  Leader1  Category 1 Reason 1
user1  Leader1  Category 1 Reason 2
user1  Leader1  Category 1 Reason 2
user1  Leader1  Category 2 Reason 1
user1  Leader1  Category 2 Reason 1
user2  Leader1  Category 1 Reason 1
user2  Leader1  Category 1 Reason 1
user2  Leader1  Category 2 Reason 1
user2  Leader1  Category 2 Reason 1
```

I'm trying to count the number of transactions a user has made and group them into those 2 categories.

I have tried the following code which can get the count for Category 1 reason but is only showing users that have that reason. I was aiming to also show users without that reason but with a count of 0. This query also falls short of counting Category 2 Reason (I can't even get near that just yet without breaking this simple one)

```
SELECT DISTINCT User.name, User.Leader, COUNT (reason) AS Reason FROM  
Transactions AS TRACKER 
INNER JOIN User AS GROUPS ON TRACKER.name=User.name
WHERE TRACKER.reason IN ('Category 1 Reason 1','Category 1 Reason 2','Category 1 Reason 3')
GROUP BY GROUPS.name, GROUPS.Leader
```

My expected result is:

```
--------------------------------------
User   Leader  Category 1   Category 2
--------------------------------------
User1  Leader1     4           2
User2  Leader1     2           2
User3  Leader2     0           0
User4  Leader2     0           0
```

but I am getting:

```
-------------------------
User   Leader  Category 1   
-------------------------
User1  Leader1     4          
User2  Leader1     2
```

Thank you in advance for  any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT u.name, u.Leader, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.reason IN ('Category 1 Reason 1', 'Category 1 Reason 2', 'Category 1 Reason 3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS reason_count
FROM User u LEFT JOIN
     Transactions t 
     ON t.name = u.name
GROUP BY u.name, u.Leader;
```

Note that this also uses a `LEFT JOIN` to keep all rows in `users`, if when there are no transactions at all.

If you want separate columns for each category reason, then extend the above logic:

```
SELECT u.name, u.Leader, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.reason IN ('Category 1 Reason 1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reason1_cnt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.reason IN ('Category 1 Reason 2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reason2_cnt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.reason IN ('Category 1 Reason 3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reason3_cnt
FROM User u LEFT JOIN
     Transactions t 
     ON t.name = u.name
GROUP BY u.name, u.Leader;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon, the query you sent works! One last thing though when I limit the result to a date range which is also on the Transactions table, the results return to just those with counts

`FROM User u LEFT JOIN
     Transactions t 
     ON t.name = u.name
WHERE t.date between '20190301' and '20190401'
GROUP BY u.name, u.Leader;`

Comment: Nix that last question @Gordon-linoff, I moved the WHERE clause to the JOIN and worked like a charm. Thanks again for your help!